# How could Hermione be in two places at the same time?

Tags: harry-potter, episode-identification

In one of the movies, I remember that Ron Weasley is confused about Hermione very busy agenda, so it seems that there are several Hermione's, or she can time travel, or being in two places at the same time.

Which of the movies is that? How could she do that?

Comment: I've downvoted for lack of research effort. Even the most casual of searches would have answered your question, including googling the question title.

Comment: Watching the movie / reading the book would also fully answer the question in fairly short order.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a Google master :(

Comment: No offense intended, but you don't need to be a "Google master" to take the exact question title you're about to use here and plug it into Google first.

Comment: @ibid Possible duplicate of the [tag:time-turner] tag? :-P

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yeah. This is one of those places where I approve of our dupe policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Prisoner of Azkaban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Prisoner_of_Azkaban) Hermione has a ["Time-Turner"](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Time-Turner) that allows for time travel, letting her be in two classes at once.

It becomes a major plot point at the end of the film.